# BluetoothServerSocket.accept() hangs when Bluetooth is disabled/enabled

Tags: android, bluetooth

How do we recover if the user disables/enables Bluetooth while our app is running?

We have an application that does Bluetooth connect without doing Bluetooth discovery, since we already know the Bluetooth MAC addresses. The server side loops on accept() on a BluetoothServerSocket, and the client side uses connect() on a BluetoothSocket. The socket connections are generally short lived, and normally everything works fine.

This is all running on a pair of Nexus One phones running 2.3.3. Some other phones -- e.g. a Sprint HTC Evo also running 2.3.3 -- do not seem to support this style of connection, even though it is decribed in the Android developer docs. None of the phones are rooted.

While our application is running, if the phones are moved out of Bluetooth proximity then near each other again, they are temporarily unable to connect, but then start connecting again, all of which makes sense.

While our application is running, if the user goes into settings and disables Bluetooth, we can no longer connect, which makes sense. When the user enables Bluetooth again, however, accept() hangs forever. This is true regardless of whether the accept() was active at the time Bluetooth was disabled. (We have code to avoid calling accept if BluetoothAdapter.isEnable is false.)

We have tried breaking out of accept() by closing the socket from another thread and then reestablishing the BluetoothServerSocket socket, but then we get "Not able to register SDP record" when we call BluetoothAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord() even though we have closed the previous socket, and the docs say close releases all resources. In the end, we have to restart our app to get things working.

So...what is supposed to happen if the user changes Bluetooth enable while an app is runnning?

Is there any way for our app to recover and start accepting Bluetooth connections?

The client side seems to handle the disruption without any trouble.

Thanks!